# Need to Subtract the Data

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to subtract the data from two sheet and get the answer into third sheet also wanted to highlight the cell if difference is more than +0.01 and -0.01

I am able to get the code to compare the data but not able to subtract the data.

```
Sub Compare()

 Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
 Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

'Clearing the contents of the third sheet for the fresh comparison

usedCoulms = ws3.UsedRange.Columns.Count
usedRows = ws3.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To usedRows
For j = 1 To usedCoulms
ws3.Cells(i, j).Value = ""
ws3.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Next
Next

'Coulmn count of first sheet
ColumnCount = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
'row count of first sheet
RowCount = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To RowCount
For j = 1 To ColumnCount
If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws2.Cells(i, j).Value Then    'Comparing if values are not equal
    ws3.Cells(1, j).Value = ws1.Cells(1, j).Value 'Copying the Header of the Mismatched Cell
    ws3.Cells(i, j).Value = CStr("MisMatch")   'If mismatch setting set value as MisMatch
    ws3.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 65535     'Highlighting with Yellow color

Else
    ws3.Cells(i, j).Value = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
    'If values are same copy the first sheets value if dont want to copy can skip this
   End If
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You should always use `Option Explicit` at the top. Also, I can't see any attempt of substracting the data... so please explain again why you are unable to substract...

Comment: I have tried "ws3.Cells(i, j).Value = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value - ws2.Cells(i, j).Value"

Comment: Are the cells a numerical type?

Comment: Yes, except 1st row and 3 column

Comment: You need to step through the code and see what is going on.

Comment: `ws3.Cells(i, j).Value = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value - ws2.Cells(i, j).Value` did not work or what? in your code this line does not appear. Also, to clear used range, you can do it with a single line of code. Use `ws3.UsedRange.Clear` and it will delete all values, and colors

Comment: No sir, its not working as few cell in the sheet are blank or with N/A, This is not in the code as I am able to compare it in the given code but not able to get the differences.

Comment: I am getting error as type mismatch as cell has @N/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FAB said above, you should always use `Option Explicit` at the top to help you find syntax errors. You had quite a few undeclared variables in your code. Instead of filling the interior of the cells with a white background-color, you can use `ws3.Cells(i,j).Clear` in order to clear the cells. Also, you had the value of `ws3.Cells(i,j) = CStr ("MisMatch")`. If you concatenate the subtracted value and the `CStr("MisMatch")`, I believe you will have your desired result. Hope this helps.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim usedColumns As Long
    Dim usedRows As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

'Clearing the contents of the third sheet for the fresh comparison

    usedColumns = ws3.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    usedRows = ws3.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ws3.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Clear

    Dim ColumnCount As Long
    'Coulmn count of first sheet
    ColumnCount = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    Dim RowCount As Long
    'row count of first sheet
    RowCount = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To RowCount
        For j = 1 To ColumnCount
            If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value <> ws2.Cells(i, j).Value Then    'Comparing if values are not equal
                ws3.Cells(1, j).Value = ws1.Cells(1, j).Value
                ws3.Cells(i, j).Value = (ws1.Cells(i, j).Value - ws2.Cells(i, j).Value) & CStr("MisMatch") 'Copying the Header of the Mismatched Cell
                   'If mismatch setting set value as MisMatch
                ws3.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 65535     'Highlighting with Yellow color

            Else
                ws3.Cells(i, j).Value = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
            'If values are same copy the first sheets value if dont want to copy can skip this
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```